# Text inside button too big autosize?

Tags: java, android

The problem I am having is when changing localisation on the application the character length for some words is longer than the previous language therefore there are sizing issues with the buttons as they were initially made just for English.

**English Locale Screenshot**

[image]

**Spanish Locale Screenshot**

[image]

I know I am able to add **android:maxLines="1"** but this wouldn't solve my issue as the text is too large. I tried using a textview auto sizer for the text size but this hasn't solved the issue.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview   
This is auto fit textview ,and surely will solve your probelm

Comment: Also check out [Android O's text view autosize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) which is also present in the support library.

Comment: @AdeelTurk Thanks, I will try this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AdeelTurk for providing this answer. I was able to use autofittextview with my buttons but it was complex here is an example of how I used it with a LinearLayout which usually don't work with this API.